# Save users chooice of stylesheet in cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am supposed to let the user change the style of a website by changing the CSS-file. After that, the users choice is to be saved in a cookie (for at least a week), and loaded the next time the user visits the website. I manage to get the code to work which allows the user to change CSS-file, but I have little clue on how to procceed with the cookie.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<link id="stylesheet_1" href="inlamning7_utseende1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="default">
    <link id="stylesheet_2" href="inlamning7_utseende2.css" type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet2" title="dark">
    <link id="stylesheet_3" href="inlamning7_utseende3.css" type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet3" title="pastell">
    <link id="stylesheet_4" href="inlamning7_utseende4.css" type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet4" title="gray">
```

And

```
<a id="style_1" class="left_sub8" onclick = "changeCSS('inlamning7_utseende1.css')" >Default</a>
<a id="style_2" class="left_sub8" onclick = "changeCSS('inlamning7_utseende2.css')">Dark</a><br>
<a id="style_3" class="left_sub8" onclick = "changeCSS('inlamning7_utseende3.css')">Pastell</a><br>
<a id="style_4" class="left_sub8" onclick = "changeCSS('inlamning7_utseende4.css')">Gray</a><br>
```

**Javascript (which enables the user to switch CSS-file)**

```
function changeCSS(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('stylesheet_1').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```

**Javascript (code for the cookie)**

```
function createCookie(cssName,value,days) {
  var exDate = new Date();
  exDate.setDate(exDate.getDate() + days);
}

function readCookie(cssName) {
  var cookie = document.cookie;
}
```

The javascript code for the cookie is an example I have provided, that represents how I THINK would be a good way to approach my problem. I suppose a cookie needs to be created when the user chooses a stylesheet. Then, the cookie needs to be read by the webpage the next time he/she visits it. Thus the choice of the two functions createCookie and readCookie. I am not supposed to use jQuery and the solution should work in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

By other words, the webpage should save the filename of the last stylesheet selected and save it to a cookie. When loaded, the page should check to see if the cookie exists and changes stylesheet accordingly.

Do any of you know how to solve my problem? Thank you in advance! And feel free to ask me to clarify if there is anything that is unclear!

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [mozilla's cookie framework](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework).  But basically to create/update a cookie do this:

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires) {
    if (!name || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(name)) { return false; }
    var sExpires = "";
    if (expires) {
      switch (expires.constructor) {
        case Number:
          sExpires = expires === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + expires;
          break;
        case String:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + expires;
          break;
        case Date:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
          break;
       }
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + expires;
    return true; // true means it succeeded whereas false means it failed to set
}
```

And to read a cookie do this:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    if (!name) { return null; }
    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(name).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
}
```

Comment: I mean you definitely need to link to your JavaScript or inline your JavaScript, but to set cookies/read cookies it's purely JS

Comment: I have a link in my HTML-document as such:
<script src="inlamning7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: May I ask what "encodeURIComponent" does? I have yet to encounter that

Comment: Well then you'll need to include this JavaScript in there and call the functions I outlined in the appropriate places (that could be `onload` or some event handler)

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` escapes a string so it can be placed in a uri.  More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Ok I see!
And thank you for the link, I will definitely take the time to check it out. 
Thank you for your help! I´ll try to apply what you´ve said to solve my problem!

Comment: Great! If this is the correct answer would you mind marking it as so? If you have additional questions, I'd recommend opening another question and going from there. It's easier to do that then hunt through the comments :)

Comment: Absolutely! Though I´ll need some time to make this work (if I can), but if it works, then I´ll mark this answer as the correct one.
Yes, that sounds like a sensible idea :)